# throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors ^ Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'favicon.ico' doesn't exist

Tags: express

**code in app.js:**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const mc = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'mysql',
    database: 'test0'
});
app.get('/account', function (req, res) {
    mc.query('SELECT * FROM account', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error: false, data: results, message: 'Todos list.' });
    });
});
```

**result:**

the same code running well in node version 8.9, after upgrade it shown the data in browser after that thrown an error in terminal

```
$ node -v
v8.11.2
$ node app.js 
Node app is running on port 8080
/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'favicon.ico' doesn't exist
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Connection.query (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:208:25)
    at /Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/app.js:35:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/Users/sugizo/Downloads/learn/test0/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
```

already search in the app for 'favicon.ico', but can't found anything contain favicon.ico

any idea? thx

Comment: Use for example :app.use(express.favicon("public/images/favicon.ico"));

Answer (score 0):

nice, thx, solved by

```
$ npm install serve-favicon --save
```

and modified app.js

```
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const path = require('path');
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'images', 'favicon.ico') ) );
```